# PackStack fails with - Error: Unable to connect to mongodb server

Tags: mongodb, openstack

Openstack - **Kilo**

OS - **CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)**


Applying 10.xx.xxx.xx_mongodb.pp

Applying 10.xx.xxx.xx_redis.pp

10.xx.xxx.xx_mongodb.pp:                        [ ERROR ]

Applying Puppet manifests                         [ ERROR ]


ERROR : Error appeared during Puppet run: 10.xx.xxx.xx_mongodb.pp

Error: Unable to connect to mongodb server! (10.xx.xxx.xx:27017)

You will find full trace in log /var/tmp/packstack/20160101-065236-2OHqyr/manifests/10.xx.xxx.xx_mongodb.pp.log

Please check log file /var/tmp/packstack/20160101-065236-2OHqyr/openstack-setup.log for more information

Additional information:

 * A new answerfile was created in: /root/packstack-answers-20160101-065237.txt

 * Time synchronization installation was skipped. Please note that unsynchronized time on server instances might be problem for some OpenStack components.

 * File /root/keystonerc_admin has been created on OpenStack client host 10.xx.xxx.xx. To use the command line tools you need to source the file.

 * To access the OpenStack Dashboard browse to 10.xx.xxx.xx/dashboard .

Please, find your login credentials stored in the keystonerc_admin in your home directory.

 * To use Nagios, browse to 10.xx.xxx.xx/nagios username: nagiosadmin, password: d11c096693bb44cd

**mabgodb.log detail**


2015-12-31T14:18:24.233-0500 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=34017 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=vcswin01.samgpunb.symantec.com

2015-12-31T14:18:24.234-0500 [initandlisten] 

2015-12-31T14:18:24.234-0500 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running on a NUMA machine.

2015-12-31T14:18:24.234-0500 [initandlisten] **          We suggest launching mongod like this to avoid performance problems:

2015-12-31T14:18:24.234-0500 [initandlisten] **              numactl --interleave=all mongod [other options]

2015-12-31T14:18:24.234-0500 [initandlisten] 

2015-12-31T14:18:24.234-0500 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.6

2015-12-31T14:18:24.234-0500 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion

2015-12-31T14:18:24.234-0500 [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

2015-12-31T14:18:24.235-0500 [initandlisten] build info: Linux c1bg.rdu2.centos.org 2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jun 19 21:14:45 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_53

2015-12-31T14:18:24.235-0500 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc

2015-12-31T14:18:24.235-0500 [initandlisten] options: { command: [ "run" ], config: "/etc/mongodb.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", http: { enabled: false }, port: 27017 }, processManagement: { fork: true, pidFilePath: "/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log", quiet: true } }

2015-12-31T14:18:24.235-0500 [initandlisten] 

2015-12-31T14:18:24.235-0500 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Readahead for /var/lib/mongodb is set to 4096KB

2015-12-31T14:18:24.235-0500 [initandlisten] **          We suggest setting it to 256KB (512 sectors) or less

2015-12-31T14:18:24.235-0500 [initandlisten] **          http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/readahead

2015-12-31T14:18:24.236-0500 [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongodb/journal

2015-12-31T14:18:24.237-0500 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed

2015-12-31T14:18:24.260-0500 [initandlisten] allocating new ns file /var/lib/mongodb/local.ns, filling with zeroes...

2015-12-31T14:18:24.293-0500 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /var/lib/mongodb/local.0, filling with zeroes...

2015-12-31T14:18:24.293-0500 [FileAllocator] creating directory /var/lib/mongodb/_tmp

2015-12-31T14:18:24.295-0500 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /var/lib/mongodb/local.0, size: 64MB,  took 0 secs

2015-12-31T14:18:24.299-0500 [initandlisten] build index on: local.startup_log properties: { v: 1, key: { _id: 1 }, name: "*id*", ns: "local.startup_log" }

2015-12-31T14:18:24.299-0500 [initandlisten]    added index to empty collection

2015-12-31T14:18:24.300-0500 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017

Answer (score 0):

For now see "Hackery setting up RDO Kilo on CentOS 7.2 with Mongodb up and running as of 01/08/2016"
http://dbaxps.blogspot.com/2016/01/set-up-rdo-kilo-on-centos-72-with.html